# After EXEC query I want to proceed further

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
Empcode Empname  COmpany   Department Question                    Scale
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1001    ABC       Comp1     IT        Development Opportunities    50
1001    ABC       Comp1     IT        Goals and Targets Set        30
1001    ABC       Comp1     IT        Feedback and Coaching        10
1002    XYZ       Comp1     IT        Goals and Targets Set        60
1002    XYZ       Comp1     IT        Feedback and Coaching        70
```

The query I tried:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Question) 
                from TmpTest1
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Empcode,Empname,Company,Department,' + @cols + '
        from 
        (
            select *
            from TmpTest1
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
           max(scale)
           for Question in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

execute(@query)
```

After I execute I want to return the result set and proceed further. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking correctly you can create a temporary table and have the result set go into a temporary table where you can do further processing before returning the final results.

Comment: Yes I got it But it should be a Global Temporary table only then i can use further after Execute Command.

Comment: To create a Global Temporary table precede the table name with two numbers signs instead of one (##temp_tbl). The global table will be dropped automatically when the session that created the table ends and all other tasks have stopped referencing them. You may consider just creating a regular table which you can empty out each time after you are done with it.